# Holomorphic function with analytic square root but no holomorphic logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, examples-counterexamples

> Give an example of a domain $U$ and a holomorphic function $f:U \to \Bbb C$ which has a holomorphic square-root but for which there does not exist a holomorphic function $F$ such that $f = \exp F$.

I am struggling to come up with an appropriate example. Could I have a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take $U=\mathbb C$ and $f(z)=z^2$.

Comment: Is there an example where $f$ does not have a $0$ in $U$?

Comment: @Reltih88 Sure. Take $U=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $f(z)=\frac1{z^2}$.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to why your examples work. Why does $f(z)=z^2$ have a holomorphic square root on $\mathbb C$? I know the obvious answer is that it is equal to $z$ but why is that? For example $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$ so I thought it was not valid to say $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: @Reltih88 I would never write $\sqrt{z^2}=z$; that doesn't even make sense. I know that $g(z)=z$ works simply because$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):g^2(z)=z^2=f(z).$$That's what being a holomorphic square root means.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. That is a better way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 3):

Take any holomorphic function $g$ that does not have a holomorphic logarithm and take $f=g^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\exp$ misses the value $0$, so if $f$ has a zero in $U$, you can't write $f=\exp{} \circ F$ for a holomorphic $F$.

On the other hand, the square root has a branch point at zero, so you need a function that has a way to avoid this. For example, $(\sqrt{z})^2 = z$ is holomorphic, so $z^2$ is suitable for this.